# angular2 quickstart cannot find name 'module'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm following Tour of Heroes tutorial for building my first app.I have written a component file threads.component.ts as follows:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'Threads',
    templateUrl: './threads.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./threads.component.css']
})
```

but I'm getting the error 'Cannot find name module',  what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a typescript error. You can add the types for node and it gets resolved:

```
 npm install -D @types/node
```

And in your tsconfig:

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
      "types" : ["node"]
  }
 ... 
}
```

Simpler version if you don't want to install types:

add this at top of your component:

```
declare var module: {
  id: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me out

Comment: declare var module: {}; fixed the same issue I was seeing in Storybook React Native with TypeScript.

Comment: `declare` works, while `compilerOptions` doesn't. I'm using WebStorm.